# Getting multiple sheets in same excel output using BIRT reporting tool(opensource version)

Tags: excel, birt

I need to get multi tabbed output in the final report output in excel fromat. I'm using birt 4.2.0. Any help????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've gathered, messing around BIRT, only way to get multi sheet (I assume this is what you consider under term multi tabbed output) in excel format, is possible using custom emitters for xls.

For more info, check out these sites:

- [Replacing default birt emitters](http://birtworld.blogspot.com/2011/07/replacing-default-birt-xls-emitter.html)
- [How to create multiple sheets in excel](http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/24629-how-to-create-multiple-sheets-in-excel-reports/)

Comment: was a bit late to thank you. Btw I'm using one of the custom emitters. I'm using modified NativeXLS emitter and it seems pretty good. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
     options = new EXCELRenderOption(outputFormat: "xls")
     options.setEmitterID("uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel.XlsEmitter" )
```

This creating 40 record per sheet for me . i think no options except the emitter so please try it , but my problem is how list them in a single sheet all of the records.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**
Migration of uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel from version 4.4.2 to 4.7.0 is caused this issue. In the updated version, pagination is enabled by default. Hence, all the table containing more than 40 rows are divided into multiple sheets, each sheet containing 40 rows.

**Resolving The Problem**
To fix this issue in IBM Rational Software Architect Designer / IBM Rational Software Architect Designer for WebSphere Version 9.6x and 9.7.x. follow below steps:

Switch to 'Report Design' perspective
Select the entire table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGQz5.png)

Go to ‘Properties Editor – Table’ -> Properties -> ‘Page Break’
Change the 'Page Break Interval' field to ‘0’(zero) to get all rows of the document in a single sheet. The default value is 40 i.e., 40 rows grouped to one sheet.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUNCg.png)